# Angular TypeError: object (_co.book) is null?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

This is what the console shows:

> ERROR TypeError: "_co.book is null"
>       View_SingleBookComponent_0 SingleBookComponent.html:3
>       Angular 24
>       RxJS 5
>       Angular 11 SingleBookComponent.html:3:4 ERROR CONTEXT  {…} ​ elDef: Object { nodeIndex: 2, bindingIndex: 0, outputIndex: 0, … } ​
>   elView: Object { def: {…}, parent: {…}, state: 1164, … } ​ nodeDef:
>   Object { nodeIndex: 3, bindingIndex: 0, outputIndex: 0, … } ​
>   nodeIndex: 3 ​ view: Object { def: {…}, parent: {…}, state: 1164, …
>   }...

The page must show the information of the book (author name and book title)

This is the single-book.component.ts code:

```
export class SingleBookComponent implements OnInit {

  book: Book;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private booksService: BooksService,
              private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.book = new Book('', '');
    const id = this.route.snapshot.params[' id'];
    this.booksService.getSingleBook(+id).then(
      (book: Book) => {
        this.book = book;
      }
    );
  }

  onBack() {
    this.router.navigate(['/books']);
  }
}

 //This is the book-form.component.ts code

export class BookFormComponent implements OnInit {
  bookForm: FormGroup;
  fileIsUploding = false;
  fileURL: string;
  fileUploaded = false;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
              private booksService: BooksService,
              private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initForm();

  }
  initForm() {
    this.bookForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      title: ['', Validators.required],
      author: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }
  onSaveBook() {
    const title = this.bookForm.get('title').value;
    const author = this.bookForm.get('author').value;
    const newBook = new Book (title, author);
    if (this.fileURL && this.fileURL !== '' ) {
      newBook.photo = this.fileURL;
    }
    this.booksService.createNewBook(newBook);
    this.router.navigate(['/book']);
  }
```

Comment: Try your html like: `*ngIf="book?.photo"`, `[src]="book?.photo"` , etc

Comment: Why would you take a pic of the code instead of copy paste it ?

Comment: @vega because it's long

Comment: Have you read how to provide [mcve]?

Comment: beacause an image cannot be copied to test, debug and help!

Comment: Oh you are right sorry :/

Answer (score 0):

add elvis operator - `?` inside html where you are using `book` like this:

```
*ngIf="book?.photo"
```

or you can also add `*ngIf="book"` to `div` element which wraps your book data

Answer (score 0):

At the time the component renders, `book` is not set. Just move `this.book = new Book('', '');` to the constructor or directly to the declaration of the variable above your constructor.

Alternatively, wrap your component's code in an `*ngIf`, for example:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="book">
   <div ...></div>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: well the errors disappeared, but there' s no data and also the back button shows and hide quickly.

Comment: Well, that's another issue then. Does `this.booksService.getSingleBook(+id)` resolve properly? Add a breakpoint there, check it out.

Comment: I am here to help, but I am not here to do your job for free, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

```
const id = this.route.snapshot.params[' id'];
```

There is a blank space before the id element which made the id null.
it should be:

```
const id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
```

or

```
const id = this.route.snapshot.params.id;
```